# Losing Session Id Every Request in Spring 3 MVC Application with Proxy by Apache

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, proxy, mod-jk

I have a web application which I am setting up a shopping cart for; the application serves many different websites, each with it's own domain.  Virtual Hosts are used to forward each domain to the Tomcat 6 server as well as set the path to that particular websites static resources; these static resources cannot be stored in the web application, and therefore are stored on the server and served through Apache.

first I use JkMount on my context root, then do URL rewrite with [P, L] for taking the context path "mywebapp" out of the URL, so when someone goes to this application with the domain `somedomain.com` the web application processes on `somedomain.com/mywebapp/store/cart`
but the browser sees `somedomain.com/store/cart`.  Until now this has been working very well; The problem is that every request is having it's session reset and I don't know why.

If I remove apache from the front end of serving the Session is not reset and works normally (as I expected).  But I can't seem to set up my virtual host to forward to the application without losing sessions.  I've read a lot about the problem but my competence is in JavaEE, and I have very little knowledge of Apache Web Server; so I'm not even sure how to begin researching the fix.

I've heard of something called ProxyPassing but I'm not sure what that means or how it works; most examples I've seen have changes to the Tomcat server.xml adding a domain, which I can't really do because domains (virtual hosts to match) get added dynamically and I can restart Apache, but can't be restarting the JavaEE application every time a new site is added.

Any ideas for fixing this, or getting to the root cause?  Any alternative approaches?

**UDPATE**:  I'm going to post my virtual host entry for one of the dynamic websites

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin test@test.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName jawesome.com
    ServerAlias www.jawesome.com
    ErrorLog "logs/jawesome_com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/jawesome_com-access.log" common

    Alias /files/ "C:/static/1/uploaded_files/"
    <Directory "C:/static/1/uploaded_files">
                Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
    </Directory>

    JkMount /webapp ajp13
    JkMount /webapp/* ajp13

    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteLogLevel 9
    #RewriteLog "/usr/local/apache/logs/testrewrite.log"

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(webapp/.*|files/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /webapp/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Path` needs to be removed from the JSESSIONID cookie. One option would be to remove it in your Tomcat setup. Add `emptySessionPath="true"` to your AJP Connector.

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" emptySessionPath="true"/>
```

The only gotcha is if you have other apps running on this same domain they would share this session id. But I don't see any in your config.

Comment: this works as advertised - change goes in Tomcat's server.xml

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a team that is managing several java webapps each with their own authentication mechanisms. We have several apache servers load balanced and we're using ProxyPass to direct traffic to the backend webapps. So far, ProxyPass works well.

Here's an example that will proxy incoming requests to and from 'mywebapp' running on a tomcat server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName somedomain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /mywebapp http://tomcat-server:8080/mywebapp
ProxyPassReverse /mywebapp http://tomcat-server:8080/mywebapp
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
...
# can put rewrite rules here
...
</VirtualHost>
```

We also use rewrite rules and they work fine with proxypass definitions like this one.

Hope this helps, Good luck.